# PHP SOAP Client - How to handle complex requests

Tags: php, soap, client

I've done a few soap-client projects already but this time I am a bit stuck. I need to submit more then just an array this time - the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <InsertAddr xmlns="http://example.com/Service/">
      <item>
        <ID>long</ID>
        <Text>string</Text>
        <Fields>
          <FieldItem>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </FieldItem>
          <FieldItem>
            <Name>string</Name>
            <Value>string</Value>
          </FieldItem>
        </Fields>
      </item>
    </InsertAddr>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Normally I would call this like

```
$response = $client->InsertAddr(array('ID' => $submID, 'Text' => $submText, .....)
```

I've tried to submit id,text and an array with the fileds but it won't work. 
Any advice what I should submit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator so you won't wonder how to construct the request. In addition you'll handle the response very easily (depending on the generator you use).

You could try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which is very complete.